# How to authenticate an API using OAuth1.0 with custom made header using Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, api, authentication, oauth, oauth-1.0a

I am working on the OAuth1.0 authorization process and here is my Java code in Spring boot,

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.mgiorda.oauth.OAuthConfig;
import com.mgiorda.oauth.OAuthConfigBuilder;
import com.mgiorda.oauth.OAuthSignature;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.*;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
//import com.example.demo.testsign;
import java.util.Collections;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.demo.controller"})
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class TestapiApplication {
    public  static String testm() {

        OAuthConfig oauthConfig = new OAuthConfigBuilder("CONSUMER KEY", "CONSUM_SECRET_KEY")
                .setTokenKeys("ACCESS TOKEN", "SECRET TOKEN")
                .build();

        OAuthSignature signature = oauthConfig.buildSignature(com.mgiorda.oauth.HttpMethod.GET, url)
                .addQueryParam("aParam", "aValue")
                .addFormUrlEncodedParam("myParam", "anotherValue")
                .create();
        return signature.getAsHeader();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String val = testm();
        //System.out.println(val);
        // request url
        String url = "htpps://khjfskdhf.com";

// create an instance of RestTemplate
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

// create headers
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
// set `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
// example of custom header

        headers.set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,val);
        System.out.println(headers);
// build the request
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

// make an HTTP GET request with headers
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                request,
                String.class
        );

// check response
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            System.out.println("Request Successful.");
            System.out.println(response.getBody());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Request Failed");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
        }
    }

}
```

I have created a header using the signature method and pass it to my main method to get authorized. But I got a 404 Not Found error, here is the error message,

```
08:13:17.464 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Response 404 NOT_FOUND
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found: [no body]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:184)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:782)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:740)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:583)
    at com.example.demo.TestapiApplication.main(TestapiApplication.java:61)
```

Could anyone let me know why its not working for me. I am really struggling to finish this up. Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Prabha

Comment: Is Oauth1 deprecated? How are you able to use the import 'com.mgiorda.oauth.OAuthConfig;' if it is deprecated? Can you link me to the mvn dependency that is used for it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by giving the URL parameter values and created a custom singing request method for a header as well.